# Buscar coincidencia de números con expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript, regex

Esta expresión regular debe encontrar el número y que el mismo no forme parte otro número más grande
Ej:

```
/\b[0-9]{4}[-\/][0-9]{3}\b/gmi
```

opción 1: 123456/0000-000 (no sea válido ya que también contiene "123456/")

opción 2: 0000-000 (si sea válido)

Cómo hago para que sólo encuentre la opción 2 y la opción 1 no?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Cómo hago para que sólo encuentre la opción 2 y la opción 1 no

Comment: @AlanGabriel ¿necesitas que la `RegEx` no acepte caracteres antes ni después? Por ejemplo: `asd0000-000` o `1233-123-54` ¿son válidos?

Comment: En estos casos necesito qué, por ejemplo:
asd0000-000 (no lo acepte ya que también contiene "asd")
1233-123-54 (no lo acepte ya que también contiene "-54")
1234-456 (sí sea acepta ya que no contiene ningún otro caracter ni adelante ni atrás)

Comment: si todo lo que contiene cada cadena o linea es esa secuencia, puedes usar los delimitadores de linea `^` (inicio) y `$` (fin), en la regex `/^[0-9]{4}[-\/][0-9]{3}$/`

Comment: @abulafia sería bueno que consideres crear una respuesta ya que tu comentario parecería ser la solución lo que el OP necesita.

Comment: @Marcos Suponiendo que sea el OP quien votó el comentario :-) En todo caso, he escrito una respuesta por si es útil a alguien más.

Answer (score 1):

Tu expresión regular `/\b[0-9]{4}[-\/][0-9]{3}\b/gmi` encajará con cualquier parte de la cadena en la que aparezcan cuatro dígitos, seguidos de un guión y seguidos de tres dígitos, con tal de que haya "fronteras de palabra" (`\b`) delante del primer grupo de 4 y detrás del segundo grupo de 3.

Por desgracia eso hace que encaje en líneas que tengan cualquier otra cosa antes del primer grupo o detrás del segundo, con tal de que estén separados de ellos por una frontera de palabra.

Si tus dato se componen únicamente de los números que quieres validar (es decir, estos números no aparecen como parte de una cadena más larga, sino que son lo unico que contienen), la solución más simple es, en vez de usar "fronteras de palabra" usar "fronteras de cadena" (o línea). Estas fronteras son los caracteres especiales `^`, que denota el inicio de la cadena (o línea) y `$`, que denota el final de la cadena (o línea).

Por tanto la expresión regular buscada sería:

```
/^[0-9]{4}[-\/][0-9]{3}$/gmi
```

[Demo aqui](https://regex101.com/r/Oj367w/1)